# Is it safe to exhaust a portable electric clothes dryer indoors?

Tags: dryer

Is it safe for us to breath in the house if the portable dryer vent blows into the house?[image]

Comment: Gas or electric dryer?

Answer (score 2):

Portable probably means electric, so yes that should be safe in the short term.

You may soon have mold problems and the like from excess moisture, if you keep doing this, but there's no immediate danger from the exhaust, as would be the case with a gas dryer which exhausts combustion products.

You could simply put clothes on hangers and set them to dry - during the winter, they dry fairly quickly just hanging on the shower curtain rod over the tub, without blowing lint around the house.

Comment: Ok... So if I put a cheesecloth over the vent, that might capture the lint? Place does not have hookup so this is the only means for laundry...n yes it's electric...as for the mold, will it help if I turn the fan in the bathroom on?

Comment: Is there a window wherever this is? If so, cut a board (wooden or insulation-foam) to the fit the opened window, then put a hole in it for a dryer vent terminal ($5-10 at the home improvement store) and you are vented. Cheesecloth might help a bit as will running the bath vent, but the fact is there's already a "lint trap" in the dryer, but plenty gets past that in practice.

Comment: The lint can collect on the walls I had this happen in a garage the hose separated I don't know how long it was like this but spider webs and the lint caught fire when I was welding, it really went fast if there would have been flammable things like curtains I am sure the flash fire from the lint would have set them on fire, defiantly made me start keeping an eye on cleaning my exhaust duct once a year, the cloth may help but I would go with a pipe out a window like ecnerwal suggests, that fire although quickly over really left a lasting impression.+

Comment: And if your walls are cold, when you dry clothes the moisture will condense on your walls and ceilings. It makes the lint stick on better, so there's always that!

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing inherently dangerous about the exhaust vent. It simply emits warm, humid air. But it also makes a mess. Clothes produce lint, and over time that lint will build up anywhere the exhaust blows.

Comment: My grandmother would tie a nylon stocking to the exhaust pipe.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it if it's an electric dryer, but there are some caveats.

- The lint will make an awful mess if you don't trap it.  You can't just stick a screen over the dryer's exhaust port because that would cause the lint to build up inside the dryer, reducing its efficiency and creating a fire hazard.  Search online for "indoor dryer vent kit" for some ideas.
- Your house may get uncomfortably warm in the summer.  If you also use an air conditioner, your power bill will go up because the air conditioner will have to dispose of the heat and humidity from the dryer.
- You may get condensation on your windows in the winter.
- If you keep your dryer in a small room or closet, you'll need to provide some ventilation.
- Using scented fabric care products may result in a very powerful smell in your house.

Answer (score 0):

The lint will become unmanageable soon.  It is no small thing.  However a bigger issue exists, the clothes are going to take considerably longer to dry.  The dryer uses the relatively dry air from the house, warms it and passes it across the clothes in the dryer.  That dry hot air is good at picking-up moisture from the  clothes. That moisture carrying air is then expelled out doors.  If you dump that air back into the house then it will be recirculated through the dryer.  That moisture laden air has far less ability to pick-up moisture from the clothes. The air can only hold so much moisture.  Pretty soon all you are doing is recirculating the same moisture over and over.

Comment: The humidity disaster you describe is not likely to be a problem if the dryer isn't shut into a tiny closet with no ventilation, particularly in heating season when the air in the house is generally dry.